# why my facebook app can't receive pages webhook?

Tags: json, facebook, webhooks, facebook-comments, facebook-messenger-bot

I tried to make a bot that responds to clients' messages and comments.
Webhook only be sent when user chat with page, but when user reply or post, I can't receive any webhook.
I have  'pages_manage_metadata' permission and set up my code for receiving page webhook.
This is my permissions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glzdV.png)

but in graph api explorer I can't see these permission

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akCh5.png)

and I can't get page access token, this wrong appear:
(my app passed app review successfully and in live mode)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBOBx.png)

So how can I solve this problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, please be sure to post code as code blocks not images.

Comment: `manage_pages` is outdated, you need to ask for one or more of the current page-related permissions instead. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/manage_pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview/permissions-features

Comment: thank you ,but I didn't ask for manage_pages permissions